# node js async - prevent immediate execution of main callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm using node js async module, and I would like to run a bunch of parallel functions. In case one of the functions returns an error, I don't want the main callback to be executed right away. I want the main callback to be executed last in any case, and I would like to get an array of items that returned an error, as well as an array of items that went OK. Is this at all possible without additional logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning error in the callback of that function, just push the error to an error array, push the ok items to an ok array, and call the callback with null as 1st argument (callback(null)) for all functions. Something like this:

```
var okArray = [];
var errorArray = [];

async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        // do something
        if (error) {
            errorArray.push(errorItem);
        } else {
            okArray.push(okItem);
        }
        callback(null);
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do something
        if (error) {
            errorArray.push(errorItem);
        } else {
            okArray.push(okItem);
        }
        callback(null);
    }
], function(err) {
    console.log(okArray);
    console.log(errorArray);
});
```

If you don't mind having just 1 array for both successful/failed functions in parallel call, parallel does return an array of results for each of the function in order listed in the array. For example:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        // do something
        if (error) {
            return callback(null, errorItem);
        }
        callback(null, okItem);
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do something
        if (error) {
            return callback(null, errorItem);
        }
        callback(null, okItem);
    }
], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); // results[0] = what 1st function returns
                          // results[1] = what 2nd function returns
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the Javascript Promise objects.

Have all your parallel functions return a promise object, stick them all into an array.
Then, do Promise.all([promises]).then(callback);
Unless your function throws an exception, you can guaratee that callback only gets called after all the functions are executed.